# Laravel 7 custom authentication does not work

Tags: php, laravel-7

I am trying make custom authentication in a Laravel 7 application. Referring to official documentation I should add a public function authenticate() in LoginController, so I tried it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
         eval(\Psy\sh()); //console debug line

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

But it seems the function is not running on login. I tested by adding debug line `eval(\Psy\sh());`, but it just not running.
Any idea how to make the function run?

Comment: does your execution hit the authenticate function? 
do a ```dd("Here!")``` to make sure it hits that function 
please confirm,

Comment: @kunz398 yes, i did that. it did not hit the function.

Comment: okay so we can conclude that it doesn't even go there you need to find the route that it hits and then edit your question

Comment: but the other functions like authenticated and showLoginForm are working just fine. This is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that older subversions of Laravel 7 doesn't have `authenticated` method but with Laravel 7.30.6, you can replace the `attemptLogin` method in your LoginController like this:

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    return Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->filled('remember'));
}
```

or if you want to specify additional conditions you can replace the `attemptLogin` like this:

```
public function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    return Auth::attempt(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'password' => $credentials['password'], 'role_id' => 1], $request->filled('remember'));
}
```

the latter according to the documentation: [Manually Authenticating Users in Laravel 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

Answer (score 0):

Error is here...

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
```

Laravel 7.x version builtin Authentication not contain method authenticate inside LoginController.php

so please replace it with authenticated as below.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this function `public function authenticate(Request $request)` according to official documentation.
please refer : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: ok but try to implement it with name authenticated may be it will work then.

Comment: those functions serve different purpose aren't they? as the name intended, authenticate is executed during user authentication process, while authenticated is executed after a user is authenticated.